# Setting up automatic submersible pump and moisture sensor

Tags: pi-3, python-3

I recently came up with the idea of using a raspberry pi to power and control a moisture sensor and a pump to automatically water a plant. It's nothing large scale, but I want it to automatically water my flower if the moisture sensor is below a certain level.

So far I have a raspberry pi 3, a GPIO cable, and a T Cobbler a Breadboard (I don't have soldering experience)

I know I need to buy a pump and a sensor. But my question is how are they supposed to connect to my pi? Do they connect to it via wires to the breadboard? Do I buys ones with a USB end to connect to my pi? I've read that the pump should be 5V. Can I connect multiple pumps and moisture sensors to my pi? Do they have to specifically be for Rpi, or can I use any 5Volt sensors or pumps?

Comment: A breadboard is terrible for anything even semi-permanent. Your connections will change every time you sneeze standing next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If just starting, start simple. Just try a [switch as an input](http://razzpisampler.oreilly.com/ch07.html) and a [LED as an output](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/hello-gpio-blinking-led-using-raspberry-pi-zero-wh-65af81718c14). You can find examples where these items are connected directly to the Raspberry Pi.

Connecting something that takes more power than the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins can handle ([a motorized pump](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22105/powering-a-3-12v-water-pump-on-raspberry-pi)) is not trivial. Also, the Raspberry Pi does not have an ADC built in. So measuring analog signals (I assume the moisture sensor involves measuring an analog signal) requires [purchasing small (commonly available) circuits](https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters/overview).

All that said, this project or projects that are similar to your description have been carried out a number of times.  I found people talking about such projects [here](https://www.hackster.io/ben-eagan/raspberry-pi-automated-plant-watering-with-website-8af2dc), [here](https://mtlynch.io/greenpithumb/), [here](http://www.switchdoc.com/smartplantpi/) and [here](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-automatically-water-your-plants-with-the-raspberry-pi-1315059).

Comment: Take a step back.  A Raspberry Pi is a computer.  It is continuously running dozens if not more programs all the time.  It can handle processing video and pulling license plate numbers off a car given the correct software.  For your project (water plants) an Arduino (which is only thinking about your program) may a better choice.  And most Arduinos (there are many), for instance and Arduino Uno, already contains an ADC feature to measure an analog signal.